# Python: pip install lxml from source using pip and cython

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, lxml, cython

I'm running a virtual environment on ubuntu and would like to install lxml from source with cython for better performance using lxml.

Normally install lxml using cython from source is straightforward

```
python setup.py build --with-cython
```

To install via PIP from source you would run

```
pip install -e setup.py
```

How do you combine the two? This is an issue because I can't get lxml installed this way into my virtualenv and will loose the performance boost by installing via a traditional pip install lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the latest version of `pip` (currently 7.0.3, upgrade with `[sudo] pip install -U pip`), you should be able to use the [`--global-option <options>`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption--global-option) flag to pass parameters to `setup.py` before the `install` command is run.

Comment: What would be the syntax to execute that in this case?